# How to align the validation errors for radio button and checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

Here i am using validation plugin, everything is working fine but the error messages displayed for radio button and check box are not properly arranged.For example here i am using two radio buttons for gender options. In that if nothing is selected the error message is displayed in between the two radio buttons. The same thing is happening for listbox also. Along with this issue i tried range option for phone number but i do no how to use range option properly. Help me on this issue.

**JSCode:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.addMethod("validNameCharacter", function (value) {
            var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
            return (pattern.test(value) > 0);
        }, "Avoid Special Characters in User Name");
        $.validator.addMethod("validPasswordCharacter", function (value) {
            var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
            return (pattern.test(value) > 0);
        });
        $.validator.addMethod("ValidSalary", function (value) {
            if (isNaN(value)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }, "Please enter a valid amount");
        var validator = $("#registrationForm").validate({
            errorClass: "error",
            validClass: "valid",
//            onkeyup: true,
//            onblur: true,
//            errorContainer: "#FormValidationErrors",
//            errorLabelContainer: $('ol', "#FormValidationErrors"),
//            wrapper: 'li',
            rules: {
                UserName: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    validNameCharacter: true
                },
                Password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    validPasswordCharacter: true
                },
                ConfirmPassword: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    validPasswordCharacter: true,
                    equalTo: "#txtPassword"
                },
                EmailId: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                Gender: "required",
                DOB: {
                    required: true,
                      date:true
                },
                PhoneNumber: {
                    required: true,
                    range: [1, 10]
                },
                Salary: {
                    ValidSalary: true
                },
                Country: {
                    required: true
                },
                JobAlert: {
                    required: true
                },
                Languages: {
                    required: true
                },
                About: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 20,
                    maxlength: 120
                },
                TermsAndConditions: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                UserName: {
                    required: "User Name is Required",
                    minlength: "Please enter atleast 4 characters ",
                    maxlength: "Please enter lessthan fifteen characters"
                },
                Password: {
                    required: "Password is Required",
                    minlength: "Please enter atleast 4 characters ",
                    maxlength: "Please enter less than fifteen characters",
                    validPasswordCharacter: "The Password you entered is invalid"
                },
                ConfirmPassword: {
                    required: "Confirm password is required",
                    minlength: "Please enter atleast 4 characters ",
                    maxlength: "Please enter less than fifteen characters",
                    validPasswordCharacter: "The Password you entered is invalid",
                    equalTo: "Password Does not matches"
                },
                EmailId: {
                    required: "Email is Required",
                    email: "Enter Valid Email"
                },
                Gender: {
                    required: "Please select the Gender"
                },
                DOB:
                {
                    required: "Please enter your Date of birth",
                },
                PhoneNumber: {
                    range: "Enter phone number between 1 to 10 characters"
                },
                Country: {
                    required: "Please select the Country"
                },
                JobAlert: {
                    required: "Please select the Job Alerting type"
                },
                Languages: {
                    required: "Please select the States"
                },
                About: {
                    minlength: "Please enter morethan 20 characters",
                    maxlength: "Please enter lessthan 120 characters"
                },
                TermsAndConditions: "Please Accept It" 
            }
        });
        $(".cancel").click(function () {
            validator.resetForm();
        });
        $("#btnChkValidForm").on('click', function () {
            var status = $("#registrationForm").valid();
            alert("Form  is : " + status + "\nTotal Number of Invalid Fields is : " + validator.numberOfInvalids());
        });

    });
```

**HTML:**

```
   <div id="UserRegistrationContainer" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% slategray; width: 100%; border: 1px solid aqua; border-radius: 11px 11px 11px 11px;" >
    <form  action="/" method="post" id="registrationForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            User Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="UserName" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            Password:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="Password" value="" id="txtPassword"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
           Confirm Password:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            Mail-ID:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="EmailId" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Gender:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male" /> 
                <label for="Gender">Male</label>
                <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female" />
                <label for="Gender" id="genderLabel">Fe Male</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                DOB:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="DOB" value="" id="txtDOB" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Present Salary:
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="Salary" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Phone Number:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="PhoneNumber" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Country:
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="Country">
                    <option value="">Select Country</option>
                    <option value="India">India</option>
                    <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                    <option value="China">China</option>
                    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                    <option value="United States">United States</option>
                    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                    <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                    <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                    Notify Job Alert:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="JobAlert" value="Email" /> Email <br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="JobAlert" value="Message" /> Message <br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="JobAlert" value="IVR" /> Voice Call <br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="JobAlert" value="Post" />  Post <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Languages Interested:
            </td>
            <td>
                 <select name="Languages" multiple="multiple" size="5">
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="C++">C++</option>
                    <option value="Java">Java</option>
                    <option value="Dot Net">Dot Net</option>
                    <option value="Vxml">Vxml</option>
                    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
                    <option value="Phython">Phython</option>
                    <option value="HTML5 CSS">HTML5 CSS</option>
                    <option value="Unix">Unix</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
                About You:
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="About" cols="33" rows="5" style="color:Gray;"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="checkbox" name="TermsAndConditions" value="" class="checkbox" />Accept Terms And Conditions                    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="">
                <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" name="Submit"/>  
                <input type="reset" id="resetForm" value="Reset" style="margin-left:15px;" class="cancel" />  
                <input type="button" id="btnChkValidForm" value="Check Form" style="margin-left:11px;" />
                <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" class="cancel" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </form>
 <div id="FormValidationErrors" class="container" style="margin-left: 325px;color:Red;">

    <ol>
    </ol>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.error  {
    background-color: #FFCECE;
    border:solid 1px red;
}
.valid {
    color:black;
}
```

**Link for my code:**
 **Link** : - http://jsfiddle.net/qHCBy/

Answer (score 1):

**Quote OP**:

> *"if nothing is selected the error message is displayed in between the two radio buttons."*

This is the default behavior.  The message (`<label>`) appears immediately after the first radio or checkbox in the group.

You would change its position using the `errorPlacement` callback function.

Check to see if it's a radio or checkbox first and position it accordingly.

This is the default callback...

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

Within your `.validate()`, do something like this...

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("type") === "radio") {
        // your custom position
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
}
```

---

**Quote OP**:

> *"Along with this issue i tried range option for phone number but i do no how to use range option properly."*

I'm really not sure what you mean but this is how you use the `range` method, same as you've implemented it.

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/range-method/

> **Description**: Makes the element require a given value range.

Makes “field” a *value* between 13 and 23:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            range: [13, 23]
        }
    }
});
```

Maybe you want the `rangelength` method instead?

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/rangelength-method/

Makes “field” between 2 and 6 *characters long*:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            rangelength: [2, 6]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have an another query in error message alignment, here i know the label id so i can place the error after the label but while creating dynamic controls how come it's possible to align error message.In this case the id may differ right?

Comment: @my1, please break your words down into sentences... I honestly can't figure out what you're trying to ask me.  I can tell you that the your `errorPlacement` callback function applies to whatever element is being validated, so you would not use an `id`.  Something like `error.parent().insertBefore(element);` or whatever is applicable.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LtAy5/  I have added my code, in that validation is happening only for textbox but not for radiobutton,xheckbox and dropdown and how to resolve that.Do you have any idea about those?

Comment: @my1, two issues with your jsFiddle... 1) Your `select` element also requires a unique `name` attribute. 2) the `.rules('add')` method only works on multiple elements when it's inside of a jQuery `.each()`.

Comment: $($elm).each(function(){$(this).rules("add", {.... });});  I tried with this but the form is not validating any controls it automatically submits. Please post your code